# Get json data from var

Tags: json

I gets following data in to a variable `fields`

```
{ data: [ '{"myObj":"asdfg"}' ] }
```

How to get the value of `myObj` to another variable? I tried `fields.myObj`.

I am trying to upload file to server using `MEANjs` and node `multiparty`

Comment: You might need to provide some more context. Are you doing something like `string json = "{ data : ...}"; Serialiser s = ... fields= s.Deserialise(json); Print(fields.myObj)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your data.

`fields` only has one property: `data`. So `fields.myObj` isn't going to work.

So, let's start with `fields.data`.

The value of that is an array. You can see the `[]`. It has only one member, so:

```
fields.data[0]
```

This is a *string*. You seem to want to treat it as an object. It happens to conform to the JSON syntax, so you can parse it:

```
JSON.parse(fields.data[0])
```

This parses into an object, so *now* you can access the `myObj` property.

```
JSON.parse(fields.data[0]).myObj
```

```js
var fields = { data: [ '{"myObj":"asdfg"}' ] };
alert(JSON.parse(fields.data[0]).myObj);
```